# Разумно ли использовать vuex в целях мультиязычности и хранения комментариев?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js

Ситуация следующая:
1.Я хочу создать мультиязычность на сайте ( переводы будут хранится в БД )
Правильно ли я делаю, что на фронте json я принимаю в state, и уже оттуда каждый компонент берет значения которые ему нужны?
2. Если у меня есть комментарии к записи на странице, то при добавлении нового мне нужно отправлять его в state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Имхо это нормально.
2. Тут есть две стратегии :

   1. При добавлении отправляете в БД новую запись, потом забираете опять все записи с бэка в стейт, компоненты за счет реактивности получают обновленные данные.
   2. Сразу добавляете в стейт, отправляете в БД новую запись, получаете ответ. В случае ошибки в ответе как-то сигнализируете пользователю, что не удача и далее предлагаете какие-то варианты: повторить запрос/откатиться на состояние до отправки.
      Второй вариант это так называемый optimistic update более сложен, но более юзер френдли.